# Perl installing cpan App::cpanminus

Tags: perl, cpan

I choose the wrong "make" executable when running cpan App::cpanminus for the first time. Now it is stuck at some error with the make file. I remember the configuration telling I can re-run the configuration with a command. Unfortunately I forget the command. Help? Where is the configuration stored, I am using git for windows mingw32.

Comment: It would be useful to show what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this isn't an `App::cpanminus` issue, you're asking how to reconfigure `cpan` itself. Here's how:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell

cpan> o conf init
```

...make your changes, and your config will automatically be saved. If you don't get your desired results if you ran with the "automatic" run set to yes, say "no" to this question:

```
Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically?
```

...and then retry installing `App::cpanminus`